# How can i make a button clicked when i just click a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, dropdown

```
    <div id="mydiv"><div>
    <button style="visibility:hidden; float:left"></button>
```

I wanna make the hidden button as is clicked when someone click the div "mydiv".

Comment: Note, you have an extra quote here: `style=" visibility:hidden;" float:left;"` should be `style="visibility:hidden;float:left;"`.

Comment: You even tagged `[onclick]` why not use that?

Comment: @Syscall yeah its just a mistake

Comment: @Luca yeah i tag onclick because my code needed a js function to make a div clickable on onclick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [AndrewL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4114907/andrewl) said, you don't need a button for this. But if you want to use a button anyways, simply assign a `eventListener` to your div that simulates a click on the button:

```
document.querySelector('#mydiv').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('button').click();
});
```

**Example**

(I added some CSS rules and an extra function for visualization.)

```js
document.querySelector('#mydiv').addEventListener('click', () => { // Listen for clicks on the div
  document.querySelector('button').click(); // Simulate a click on the button
});

function test() { // This function gets called when clicking the button
  console.log("Click!");
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: red;">
  <div>
    <button style=" visibility:hidden; float:left; " onclick="test()"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @HassanElkhalifte I'm glad my answer is helpful! Please consider marking it as the accepted answer, so it's easier for future users to find a solution if they are facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a hidden button for this. Just assign a click listener to the div itself using js like this:

```
const btn = document.getElementById('mydiv');

function doSomething(){
    //run your script here when div is clicked
}

btn.addEventListener('click', doSomething);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the hidden button to catch the click event. But if you really need it:

```
<div id="mydiv" onclick="document.getElementById('btn').click()">click on me<div>
    <button id="btn" style="display:none;" ></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
$('#div_id').click(function(){$('#btn_id').trigger('click');});

$('#btn_id').click(function(){//Business logic here on btn click
});
```